# sums of quadratic forms over finite abelian groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group. Let $q:A\times A\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be a non-degenerate bicharacter (that is: for every $a\in A$ $q(a,-)$ and $q(-,a)$ are characters of $A$, which are trivial if and only if $a=1$).

What can we say about the sum $$\sum_{a\in A}q(a,a)$$ (where the sum is being taken in $\mathbb{C}$?)

Can this sum be expressed by any invariants of $q$ or of $A$?

Comment: If $A$ is cyclic then this is an example of a [quadratic Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum), which have been computed by Gauss.

Comment: @t.c., I think that further $\lvert A\rvert$ should be prime, no?

Comment: @LSpice, I'm not sure whether calling the sum a ``quadratic Gauss sum'' agrees with standard usage when $|A|$ is not prime, but I think at least that the computation is still ok: if $A=\mathbb Z/n$, then $q$ has the form $q(a,b)=\exp(2\pi i abc /n)$ for some $c\in (\mathbb Z/n)^*$, and the sum is $\sum_{a\in \mathbb Z/n} \exp(2\pi i a^2 c/n)$, which I believe was computed by Gauss.

Comment: @t.c. I can see how to reduce to the case where $|A|$ is a prime power. However: how do we reduce the non-cyclic case to the cyclic case?

Comment: @EhudMeir The reduction to the cyclic case is not at all obvious (to me). But Chapter 5 of Scharlau's book [Quadratic and Hermitian Forms](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=770063) appears to be very relevant.